# Alternative Lie structure on the space of smooth vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

Assume  that $L=(\mathbb{R}^n,, [\;\;.\;\;])$ is  a  Lie  algebra  structure  on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Associated with $L$, there is  a  natural  Lie  algebra  structure  $\tilde{L}$ on $\chi^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the  space  of  smooth  vector  fields  on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as follows:

$$ [f \partial/\partial{x_i}, g\partial/\partial{x_j}]=fg[\partial/\partial{x_i}, \partial/\partial{x_j}]+(f\partial g/\partial x_i) \partial/\partial{x_j}-(g\partial f/\partial x_j) \partial/\partial{x_i}$$

> Is it true  to say that $L_1\simeq L_2$  if  and  only  if $\tilde{L_1}\simeq \tilde{L_2}?$